# Placeholder in mat-autoComplete does not work as illustrated in the Angular Material Documentation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the same exact code provided in the angular material documentations. As per the Angular Material Website, the example for angular material's 
**mat-Autocomplete** control works as follows

[Behaviour as per Angular Material Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGOYR.png)

But my page the placeholder stays on top and does not work this way

[Behaviour in my local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCr37.png)

The problem is that the placeholder which is supposed to appear on the input field does not appear and I always see the small place holder above the input field. It does not disappear even when I am editing the input fields.

Am Scratching my head for a while. Can I be provided with tips on what could I be doing wrong possibly

The code that I am using in my local HTML

```
<form class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Plan" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
          <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
              {{ option }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
```

Code in my typescript file

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { FormControl, Form } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-my-component',
        templateUrl: './app-my-component.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app-my-component.component.scss']
    })
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
        myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
        options = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
        filteredOptions: Observable;

        constructor(private router: Router) { }

        filter(val: string): string[] {
            return this.options
                .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            try {
                // temp code
                this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
                    startWith(''),
                    map(val => this.filter(val))
                );
                // end of temp code
            } catch (exception) {
                // ....
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added material theme in your style.css?

Comment: This image illustrates the instance when you have a value in it. How does it appear when it has no input value?

Comment: The documentation does not seem to speak about that with respect to this example. I am not sure about the material theme, but I did include the material module and auto complete/type a head stuffs are working fine but not this place holder???

Comment: `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` add this to your style.css and see whether it works or not

Comment: What is the problem? Color? Size?

Comment: The problem is that the placeholder which is supposed to appear on the input field does not appear and I always see the small place holder above the input field(which is actually a label put by the angular material). Neither does it disappear when I am editing the input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have employed the following SCSS work around for the time being. This is definitely not a direct solution to the posted problem, but lets me work around it with acceptable behavior.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-placeholder-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
}

input {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {            
        font-size: 14px !important;
        color: #818181 !important;
    }
    &::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 19+ */
        font-size: 14px !important;
        color: #818181 !important;
    }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {
        /* IE 10+ */
        font-size: 14px !important;
        color: #818181 !important;
    }
    &:-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 18- */            
        font-size: 14px !important;
        color: #818181 !important;
    }
}
```

It works as illustrated in the following screen shot
[- work around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3WAu.png)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [class]="'blue-bg'">
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of simpleOptions" [value]="option">
  {{ option }}
 </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```